# "Joined field with this alias is already declared" sort by custom attribute shows error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, sorting, custom-attributes

I already had one custom sort by attribute which is agency_id but when i try to add new sort by attribute Location it shows me this error.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:48:"Joined field with this alias is already declared";i:1;s:3988:"#0 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(695): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Joined field wi...')
#1 /home/test/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(104): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->joinField('value', 'customer_entity...', 'value', 'entity_id=agenc...', Array, 'left')
#2 /home/test/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(196): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
#3 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#4 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#5 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('search_result_l...', true)
#6 /home/test/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Advanced/Result.php(103): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('search_result_l...')
#7 /home/test/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml(58): Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Result->getProductListHtml()
```

i did changes in 
*/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php*

i added code in _getProductCollection() as below

```
$sortBy = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order');
$dir = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir');
if($sortBy == "review"){
    /* added for rating */
    $this->_productCollection->joinField('review', 'review_entity_summary', 'rating_summary', 'entity_pk_value=entity_id', array('entity_type'=>1, 'store_id'=> Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()), 'left');
    /* added for rating */
}elseif($sortBy == "agency_id"){
    /* added for sort by agency id */
    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('agency_id',array('neq'=>'1111'));
    $this->_productCollection->joinField('value', 'customer_entity_varchar', 'value', 'entity_id=agency_id', array('attribute_id'=>5), 'left');
    $this->_productCollection->setOrder('value', $dir);

}elseif($sortBy == "package_location"){
    /* added for sort by Location */
    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('package_location',array('neq'=>'1111'));
    // $this->_productCollection->joinField('value', 'eav_attribute_option_value', 'value', 'option_id=package_location', array('attribute_id'=>197), 'left');
    // $this->_productCollection->setOrder('value', $dir);

}
```

before i added condition of package_location, agency_id was working fine.

i found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21331/a-joint-field-with-this-alias-bestsellers-is-already-declared-product-sortin) question but its different.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `joinField` call on the product collection is executed multiple times during one request. Likely, but not necessarily, this happens at the exact same line of code.

The field alias (first parameter) must be unique though. Make sure the relation is only joined once on initial collection allocation.

Comment: i did try with different alias but same error. :(

Comment: by the way when i print collection it shows fine.

Comment: Changing the alias does not help if it's the same line of code that causes the error.

Comment: then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's because _getProductCollection() is called multiple times across the whole PHP process. My solution is to use a static variable inside _getProductCollection():

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
  static $joined = false;

  ......

  if (!$joined) {
    // do joinField() here
    $joined = true;
  }

  ......

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one by changing alias name, I have changed alias to "rate"

```
case 'top_rated':
                    if(!strpos((string)$collection->getSelect(), 'rate') > 0) {
                        $collection->joinField(
                            'rate',                // alias
                            'review_entity_summary',      // table
                            'rating_summary',               // field
                            'entity_pk_value=entity_id',    // bind
                            array(
                                'entity_type' => 1, 
                                'store_id' => 4
                            ),                              // conditions
                            'left'                          // join type
                        );
                        $collection->getSelect()->order('rating_summary desc'); 
                    }
```

Comment: i was stuck with this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261724/magento-2-curl-api-token-return-null) can u plz help me @Umar

Comment: @divyasekar I have posted answer on ur link pls check

Comment: I will check and update u @umar thank for your effective reply

Comment: i was used this [payment-gateway](http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/gg/corporate-gateway-guide/content/directintegration/quickstart.htm) @umar